# Rewrite subdomain to folder keeping the URL unchanged

Tags: redirects, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm on a cheap shared hosting with Apache and I'm trying to do the following rewrite with `.htaccess`:

- `http://anything.example.com/par1/par2` => `http://example.com/anything/index.php?a=par1&b=par2`

To do this I have the following `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1/index.php?section=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

And this works actually. The problem is that if I put `http://digitalcameras.example.com/nikon/123` to the web browser address string and press Enter, the string becomes like this:

```
http://example.com/digitalcameras/nikon/123
```

(Note that the `digitalcameras` part moved from the beginning to the middle).

`index.php` placed in the `/digitalcameras` folder.

So the question is: can I do the same thing without changing the address in the browser?

Comment: I assume the subdomain and main domain point to the same filesystem? Where does the subdomain point to on the filesystem, in relation to the main domains document root?

Comment: @w3dk if I understand your question right than the answer is **yes**. Please see my comment to your answer. BTW - thank you for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

When you specify an absolute URL (scheme + hostname) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* it will implicitly trigger an *external redirect* - which is what you are seeing.

However, if the subdomain(s) and main domain are all on the same shared hosting account (ie. the same filesystem) then you shouldn't have to explicitly specify the full domain in the *susbstitution*, just specify the file system path.

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

The `NC` and `QSA` flags would seem to be superfluous here. The query string is appended by default, unless you explicitly include a query string in the *substitution*. And the pattern anchors (`^` and `$`) are not required either when using a match everything `.*` pattern.

---

**UPDATE#1:** The first `RewriteRule` would seem to be superfluous. This is a *wildcard* subdomain, so I assume the subdomain points to the same document root as the main domain.

What you are really trying to do is *internally rewrite* `http://anything.example.com/par1/par2` to `/anything/index.php?a=par1&b=par2` on the same *subdomain*.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ %1/index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag is required here, if the original request (pretty URL) could have a query string, which needs to be passed through.

No need to escape the dot in a *character class* in order to match a literal dot.

The `RewriteCond` directive checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable prevents a potential rewrite loop (which would result in a 500 error in the browser).

**UPDATE#2:** To avoid the explicit use of the domain (eg. `example.com`) then you could just match the first domain segment, ie. upto the first dot. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.])+
```

However, this would also match the main apex domain (or `www`), unless you already have a directive to block that. I assume accessing the main domain like this would strictly be invalid? However, this might be OK if your script handles such an invalid request with a 404?

Or, to match only subdomains of the main domain, except for `www` then try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.])+\.[a-z-]\.(com|co\.uk|net) [NC]
```

You would need to add the TLDs as required (maybe that could be generalised further?).

Comment: I made the changes: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/c/username/public_html/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`. But I've got Internal server error now :( The changes was as you intended?

Comment: A root-relative _substitution_ is relative to the document root, rather than the server root. So it should probably just be `/%1/$1`.

Comment: Presumably this `.htaccess` file is in the root directory of the main domain and not the root directory of the subdomain? So, the subdomain simply points to a subdirectory off the main domains document root?

Comment: Yes. `.htaccess` is in the root directory (`/home/c/username/public_html/`. I made the changes (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`) still have 500 error.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to join both rewrite rules into one? So by ONE rule redirect `subdomain.example.com/1/2` to `example.com/index.php?a=subdomain&b=1&c=2`? Is it possible?

Comment: Is this a wildcard subdomain? As otherwise you wouldn't normally expect to have to do such a rewrite? For instance, if the subdomain already pointed to the subdirectory then this would result in a rewrite loop.

Comment: Yes - it is wildcard subdomain. `RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]` did not worked :( I will try to do a single rule rewrite to work...

Comment: Yes, the first `RewriteRule` would seem to be superfluous and can be "joined" with the second. I'll update my answer. (Sorry, I don't think I read it your question properly the first time!)

Comment: Another update to avoid a rewrite loop (were you getting a rewrite loop?).

Comment: No! There was no loop. All worked flawlessly!!! :)))) Is it possible to avoid of explicit use of domain name to make the `htaccess` "universal"?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more "universal" domain check.